# Where to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints in Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5, autolayout

I need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`. By default it is set to `YES` (to assist with the majority of apps that are transitioning from struts and springs to the new Auto Layout).

Is  there somewhere in Xcode where the default can be changed from `YES` to `NO`?

Or do I have to manually set it for every view?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a great question - and one I've tried to find an answer to myself. Sadly, it looks like there is no "quick fix". Currently, Apple considers Constraint-based layout Opt-in - even naming a section of the [`UIView` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

> Opting in to Constraint-Based Layout

But that Opt-in is not global. I presume this is because not everything looks good if you just turn Springs & Struts into Constraints. Some UI elements break, or you would get a ton of unsatisfiable constraints errors.

I can think of one *possible* solution - I have not tried it myself, but you could make a category on `UIView` that sets **all** `UIView` objects to return `NO` for `- (BOOL)translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. While I do not know what this would break, it would globally set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.

Here is [a good introduction to Categories if you want to learn more about them](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html)!

Comment: How do you use a category to set all UIView object to return no? Category method only applies to an instance.

Comment: This answer has been accepted, but did it work? I would expect this approach to be problematic.

Comment: The category method clobbers the original method, @Boon, and each instance uses the new implementation. [Unless the original method was itself implemented in a category](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7013922/603977).

Answer (score 22):

I'm late to this question, but the mentioned option is still missing in Xcode 5 & 6, so the question is still meaningful.

Actually, we can always set a value to any property of a view/control/object by adding a **User Defined Runtime Atribute** in Storyboard (Interface Builder) like the following screenshot.

And it also works for **translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints**. So the question could be solved.

[image]

Comment: This is a slick solution, but I believe it was causing a "freeze" in XCode 6.3 beta 2.  When I removed it, my view loaded properly.. but with it, it was crashing after I upgraded to beta 2.

Comment: This works correctly in XCode 9 and iOS 11 for anyone that's looking for an updated solution. This should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 5):

When u have to change the size or position of your subview. Use `(BOOL)translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` method before you set the frame of your subview.

```
[self.benchmarkButton removeFromSuperview];
[self.benchmarkButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[self.benchmarkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, self.benchmarkButton.frame.origin.y+40, 260, 30)];
[self.benchmarksView addSubview:self.benchmarkButton];
```

Thats way your subview will not fight from constraints as it is default (AutoLayout) in Xcode 4.3 and later. Thanks

Comment: Nice, but I'm guessing you could end up with conflicts doing it this way, instead of thinking about working with the existing constraints.

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation, this property is automatically set to `NO` if the view is added through Interface Builder.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Comment: Good spot. Note that UICollectionViewCell contentViews are an exception to this.