# How to expand UICollectionView frame size dynamically in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview

Using storyboard, I added, Scrollview -> View -> CollectionView.

my_collxn_view frame size is, **(5, 200, 310, 368)**,
my_view frame size is, **(0, 0, 320, 568)**,
my_scroll_view frame size is, **(0, 0, 320, 568)**

I am having 10 Cells. So Content size is too large. I don't know how to expand UICollectionView frame size through coding. Kindly guide me.
I have tried something. My coding is below.

**First Attempt**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        my_collxn_view.frame.size.height = my_collxn_view.contentSize.height //635.0
        my_view.frame.size.height = 200 + my_collxn_view.frame.size.height //835.0

        my_scroll_view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, my_view.frame.size.height) //Scrolling
        my_collxn_view.frame = CGRectMake(5, 200, 310, my_collxn_view.frame.size.height) //Not Expanding
        return CGSizeMake(150, 205) //CELL Size
    }
```

**Second Attepmt**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()


        my_collxn_view.frame.size.height = my_collxn_view.contentSize.height //635.0
        my_view.frame.size.height = 200 + my_collxn_view.frame.size.height  //835.0

        my_collxn_view.frame = CGRectMake(5, 200, 320, my_collxn_view.frame.size.height) //Not Expanding
        my_view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, my_view.frame.size.height)  //Not Expanding 
        my_scroll_view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, my_view.frame.size.height) //Scrolling
    }
```

**Updated**

```
my_view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
my_collxn_view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
```

I have used the above two lines. Exact output received. But, Some warnings has been displayed in debug area.

**Warning**

```
2015-04-21 18:43:52.974 E Commerce[9475:1673654] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf6958a010 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(200)-[UICollectionView:0x7fcf6a84b000]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcf6957abe0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf6958a0b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UICollectionView:0x7fcf6a84b000(368)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf696745c0 h=--& v=--& UICollectionView:0x7fcf6a84b000.midY == + 517.5>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf6958a010 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(200)-[UICollectionView:0x7fcf6a84b000]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fcf6957abe0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-04-21 18:43:52.978 Test_work[9475:1673654] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf6958a0b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UICollectionView:0x7fcf6a84b000(368)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf69674630 h=--& v=--& V:[UICollectionView:0x7fcf6a84b000(635)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf6958a0b0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UICollectionView:0x7fcf6a84b000(368)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-04-21 18:43:52.980 Test_work[9475:1673654] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf6958a6c0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcf6957abe0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x7fcf6957a8b0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf6958a760 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIView:0x7fcf6957abe0(568)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf69674910 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7fcf6957abe0.midY == + 442.5>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf6958a6c0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fcf6957abe0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x7fcf6957a8b0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-04-21 18:43:52.990 Test_work[9475:1673654] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf6958a760 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIView:0x7fcf6957abe0(568)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf69674980 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7fcf6957abe0(885)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fcf6958a760 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIView:0x7fcf6957abe0(568)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Kindly guide me.

Comment: Where did you learn to name your variables like that?

Comment: I have edited. Just guide me, if you know.

Comment: Please consider a tutorial as I'm not sure where you got your knowledge from as a collection view is a scroll view so you don't need to embed it in one http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1

Comment: are you using autolayout

Comment: I am using constraints. So I am using auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

`Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`

You need to `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` on each view you manually set one or more `NSLayoutConstraint` to.

Comment: Then how to solve my issue? I am using constraints, so I can't disable autolayout. How can I expand this collection view?

Comment: @McDonal_11 On each view you add constraints to you should call `setTranslatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)`, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204082/where-to-set-translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints-in-xcode-4-5) is some more information on why you need to do this.